# SQL as percentage rather than total

Tags: sql

My current query:

```
SELECT Delaytype, SUM('Delayhours') as cnt 
FROM delays 
GROUP BY Delaytype;
```

How do I get `cnt` as a percentage rather than a sum of the total occurrences?

Comment: Percentage of what, all delays?

Comment: So currently I get Delaytype - engineering = 4 Human error = 5 I want the 4 and 5(delay hours) as a percentage not a total of all engineering  and human error delays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
SELECT Delaytype, SUM(Delayhours) / (SELECT SUM(Delayhours) FROM delays) * 100 as cntper 
FROM delays 
GROUP BY Delaytype
```

Or, if your DB supports subselects, this should be more efficient:

```
SELECT Delaytype, cnt / SUM(cnt) * 100 FROM (
  SELECT Delaytype, SUM(Delayhours) as cnt
  FROM delays 
  GROUP BY Delaytype
) AS GroupedDelays
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to cross join the total sum:

```
SELECT     d.Delaytype, SUM(d.Delayhours)/total_delay as pct
FROM       delays 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(Delayhours) AS total_delay
            FROM   delays) t
GROUP BY   d.Delaytype;
```